# title text overlaps title back button in CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

hopefully someone could help out with this.
As you can see in the image, the title is overlapping the back button in the title bar.
I have tried to add margins but I don't get the result I need.
I'm using a CollapsingToolbarLayout, and when it's expanded it shows an image and 2 TextViews with the title and a subtitle.
when the CollapsingToolbarLayout is collapsed, I just want to show the title, so the user can have more room to read the body.
However, when it's collapsed, the title text overlaps the back button in the title bar.
How can I fix this?

EDIT: I have tried removing/modifying this line: `app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"`but that didn't fix the problem.
Also, I have added a relevant code which makes the CollapsingToolbarLayout set a title when it's collapsed.

[image]
[image]

This is my xml layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/meta_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"

            android:background="#333"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/detail_metabar_vert_padding"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/detail_inner_horiz_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/detail_inner_horiz_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/detail_metabar_vert_padding"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/article_title"
                style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.9"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/detail_metabar_title_bottom_padding"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="@dimen/detail_title_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/article_byline"
                style="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#8fff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_body"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/detail_inner_horiz_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/detail_inner_horiz_margin"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="@fraction/detail_body_line_spacing_multiplier"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/detail_body_bottom_margin"
        android:textColor="@color/ltgray"
        android:textColorLink="@color/theme_accent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/detail_body_text_size" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/share_fab"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/add_fab_background"
    android:contentDescription="@string/action_share"
    android:elevation="@dimen/fab_elevation"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_share"
    android:stateListAnimator="@anim/fab_state_list_anim" />
```

This piece of code makes the CollapsingToolbarLayout set a title when it's collapsed:

```
mCollapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout_detail);
    AppBarLayout mAppBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.app_bar_detail);

    mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            if (verticalOffset == -mCollapsingToolbarLayout.getHeight() + mToolbar.getHeight()) {
                mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(titleView.getText());
            }else
                mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("");
        }
    });
```

Comment: app:expandedTitleMarginStart="56dp"

Comment: @MohitYadav nope, that didn't fix the problem. I updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: i put an ans try that

Comment: Thank you for your question, your question helped me to get answer , :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by adding the following line in my Toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          ...
          app:contentInsetStart="72dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line:

```
app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
```

---

> Updated:

Update your toolbar as:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="64dp"
         app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
         app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
```

Comment: nope, that didn't fix the problem. I updated my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                    <TextView>
                    <yourOtherViews>

                   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

                   </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```